# When i do this cog command more than once then it gives an error discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I made a help command and when i execute the command once then it works but after that it stops working meaning i have to re run the whole code. (btw this is a cog) The error that i get if i do the command more than once is `Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class help(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client



  @commands.command()
  async def help(self, ctx, cmd = "help"):
    self.client.remove_command("help")
    
    #help
    if cmd == "help":
      help_help_embed = discord.Embed(title = "Help Command", color = 0x00fd00)
      help_help_embed.add_field(name = "**:scroll: Info**", value = "`//help info`", inline = True)
      help_help_embed.add_field(name = "**:shield:Moderation**", value = "`//help moderation`", inline = True)
      help_help_embed.add_field(name = "**Channel**", value = "`//help channel`", inline = True)
      help_help_embed.add_field(name = "**:laughing: Fun**", value = "`//help fun`", inline = True)
      help_help_embed.add_field(name = "**:tools: Utility**", value = "`//help utility`", inline = True)
      help_help_embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = help_help_embed)

    #info
    if cmd == "info":
      info_help_embed = discord.Embed(title = "**:scroll: Info Commands**", description = "//help {command}", color = 0x00fd00)
      info_help_embed.add_field(name = "Commands:", value = "`help`, `changelog`, `announcements`, `ping`, `credits`", inline = False)
      info_help_embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = info_help_embed)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(help(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... maybe remove the

```
self.client.remove_command("help")
```

line? It sounds like it might be removing the command.

**EDIT:** Based on comments, it sounds like it should belong in `__init__` instead.

Comment: This removes the "standard" help command so that you are able to make your own one.

Comment: But it's within the `help` handler, meaning that when `help` is called, it removes itself.

Comment: Your edit states it perfectly, should be in the `__init__` function.

Comment: i know im not meant to say thank you because im not suggesting an improvement but it feels wrong to not say thanks so... Thanks :)